# nested select mysql operand should contains 1 columns

Tags: mysql, select, nested

```
----------------------------
| user   | path    | active |
----------------------------
| user A | A.1     |   0    |
----------------------------
| user B | A.1.1   |   1    |
----------------------------
| user C | A.1.1.1 |   1    |
----------------------------
```

conditions :

path is like a user tree.
user B is the child of user A, and user C is the child of user B.
if active = 0 it means that the user is not active.

i need to select by path the child of user A who is active and also have a child.

for now i already have a query to select the child of user A

```
select path from table where active = 1 and `path` like 'A.1%' and 
length(`path`) - length(replace(`path`, '.', '')) = 2;
```

it will return all childs of user A.

right now i need to select the child of user A who also have a child.

i tried to user nested select like this

```
select distinct path from table where active = 1 and user_type = 1 and `path` like ((select path from acctProgress_monthly where active = 1 and user_type = 1 and `path` like 'A.1%' and 
length(`path`) - length(replace(`path`, '.', '')) = 2), '%');
```

but it returns error "operand should contain 1 column"

can someone help me about this problem

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In `mysql` when you want to use nested `SELECT` it MUST return 1 value.

Imagine myNames table to be like:

**id | name**

1  | *John*

2  | *Anne*

If you do

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name = (SELECT name FROM myNames);`

will throw that error because `(SELECT name FROM myNames)` would return multiple rows.

To fix it you need to only return 1 row and 1 column (1 value):

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name = (SELECT name FROM myNames WHERE id = 1);`